# Create file in C# from source code

Tags: c#, .net, file

I'm looking for a way to create a file from a source code (when you open a file in for example notepad it gives you some code, with that code I want to recreate the file, by stating the filetype and filename and then the code that should be in the file.

I hope you can understand my problem, it's a bit hard to explain, I'll go again...

I've got the sourcecode + filename + filetype + file description for the file that I want to create. >
Now I want C# to create a file based on that information and make it an exact copy of what that information is taken from. It should save the file, and then the file is to be openable.

Thank you in advance,
Mike

Comment: So... you wish to know how to copy a file...?

Comment: No, I need to know how to, by these details, create a file. Because I don't actually have the file physically, only the details of it (which could theoretically create the file)...

Answer (score 3):

Write "code" into a file mycode.cs

```
string code = "code";
string filename = "mycode";
string filetype = "cs";
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filename+"."+filetype))
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(code);
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will try this. Will it work for like .png files and .pdf files as well?

Comment: As it appears, this snippet works for UTF-8 encoded text files.  To write binary content (.png .pdf) use BinaryWriter(), e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720464(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use the [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method?

```
file.Copy("c:\temp\source.txt", "c:\temp\dest.txt");
```

Comment: No, because the file is not parsed from my application, it is sent to me with these details, I don't have the actual file, only these details. Thank's anyways.